# Comparing two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's a bit tough to explain, but will illustrate by below tables.

```
ID   names     pages
1   maths_1      2  
1   maths_2      2
2   history      1
3   economics    1
4   physics      1
```

The table shows `book_id` and `book_name` and total pages it has

- maths_1 represents unit 1 in maths
- maths_2 represents unit 2 in maths

So total maths book has 2 pages

My question is: if `maths_3` is there in the table. if the table exits like below

```
ID   names     pages
 1   maths_1     2  
 1   maths_2     2
 1   maths_3     2
 2   history     1
 3   economics   1
 4   physics     1
```

there is one more page called maths_3 but the count still has 2 pages. In this case, I want output something like below which will be easy for me to pick the odd on out

Desired output:

```
  ID   names   pages  difference
   1    3       2        1
   2    1       1        0
   3    1       1        0
   4    1       1        0
```

Table name : BOOK

I used this query just to get the counts but can anyone help to get the difference

```
select 
    id, count(names) pagesbynames,
    MAX(pages) pagesentered 
from 
    book 
group by 
    id
```

From above query I get this output:

```
ID   pagesbynames   pagesentered  
 1        3               2    
 2        1               1    
 3        1               1     
 4        1               1
```

Stuck here, please someone help me to get the desired output

Comment: `count(names) - max(pages)`

Comment: missed that simple logic, anyways thanks

Comment: Gordon, Can i get only difference not equal to 0 rows at output

Comment: @GEEK - `HAVING count(names) - max(pages) <> 0`